# Get webform submissions filtered by data value

Tags: webforms

I have 2 webforms set up, one form collects the user email address and emails the user some info, the second form collects their email address again and needs to select the previous form's submitted data from the database and forward this onto a selected user.

Is there an efficient method for selecting webform data filtered by a field, rather than nid or sid, (in my case it would be an email address)?

Answer (score 1):

The `$filters` parameter on [`webform_get_submissions()`](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!webform!includes!webform.submissions.inc/function/webform_get_submissions/7) can be used for field filtering. The function's code loops over the filters and adds them as conditions.

```
foreach ($filters as $column => $value) {
  $pager_query->condition($column, $value);
}
```

So something like:

```
$old_form_submission = webform_get_submissions(array('email_field_name'=> $provided_email));
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, but it doesn't work, returns an error 'Column not found: 1054 Unknown column'. So it doesn't look like it works on data fields.

Comment: Did you check the field name?  Obviously the one I provided is a junk example.  Check the field name against the database and make sure it's right.

Comment: Is that the 'Field Key'?

Comment: The info I need to filter on is in the 'data' column of the 'webform_submitted_data' table, there are no columns in the database that are named after form fields, maybe I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I know that in Webform 4.x, you can select a certain array of fields to print to download by navigating to your webform, and then going to the download area. I use this to grab email address's for everyone who has opted in for newsletters, so that I can compile a list of first names, last names, and email address's to import into Mail Chimp.